# I want to undo a merge with master locally, but it gives me a fatal error

Tags: git, git-merge

I had a local branch that was older, so I wanted to update it with changes from the remote master while keeping the local changes I had made to it.

So I did this:

`git checkout master`

`git pull master`

`git checkout my_local_branch`

`git merge master`

This ruined my local branch and made it basically just a clone of master.

Luckily(I think?) I never committed it or pushed it to origin.

So I want to undo the merge.

But I tried , `git merge --abort` and it tells me:

`fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).`

Also the history is all different because basically it looks just like master.

Is there a way to fix my local branch so that it reverts back to what it looked like before I merged it with master?

Here is what git reflog shows:

```
51f03ce5 (HEAD -> my_local_branch, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) HEAD@{0}: merge master: Fast-forward
4b2e85a3 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to my_local_branch
51f03ce5 (HEAD -> my_local_branch, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) HEAD@{2}: pull: Fast-forward
949c9d1f HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from my_local_branch to master
```

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer : if the merge was a simple fast-forward, you're not "in merging" any more, the merge is done so it can't be aborted. Check your reflog with `git reflog` to search for the previous position (commit hash) for your branch. Then you'll just need to reset to that.

Comment: (Alternatively, if your branch has been pushed before the bad merge, it might be easier to reset to it.)

Comment: @RomainValeri I haven't pushed anything. This was always a local branch.  I updated my question to show what `git reflog` shows..I'm not sure what it means

Comment: Seems you're looking for `4b2e85a3` here. Before resetting your branch, maybe first create a branch and check that it's what you wanted to recover with `git checkout -b recovery_branch 4b2e85a3`. If you're OK with it, just make your branch point there with (from your branch) `git reset --hard recovery_branch`